# Git push works on Amazon EC2 but not Heroku. How do I check my logs?

Tags: git, heroku, amazon-ec2

This works on my amazon EC2

```
node app.js
Express server listening on port 3000
```

But when I do this

```
git add .
git commit -m "Added everything"

git push staging-heroku staging:master
Everything up to date
```

And I go to myapp-s.heroku.com I get this

[image]

"Check your logs for details"

**How do I check my logs to see what's wrong?**

If I do this

```
git checkout staging
git commmit -m "Added stuff"
git push origin staging
```

And I go to

```
github.com/MyName/MyApp/tree/staging
```

everything's all there. It should be working fine on Heroku but I can't see what went wrong.

## Update

I tried

```
heroku logs
Enable Logplex by myemail@gmail.com
Release v2 created by myemail@gmail.com
```

I still don't see how to find out what's going wrong with my heroku deployment :(

## Fixed

If you're having the same problem as me, try going to the heroku website and adding a dyno to app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a read of the Heroku guides

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval